# How to allow access permission from wso2is to wso2api manager using ReadWriteLDAPUserStore

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-business-process, wso2-appm, wso2-identity-server

When i create user's roles in wso2 identity server and give some permissions to roles and then configure wso2is using ReadWriteLDAPUserStore with wso2 api manager or wso2 business server then in wso2is role's permissions not visible to wso2 api manager or wso2 business process server.

am using wso2is-5.3.0 and wso2am-2.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Role permissions are not stored in the user store. They're stored in the `UM_DB`. So you have to share that database among the 2 nodes.

On a related note: APIM 2.5.0 compatible IS version is 5.6.0.

Comment: how to share UM_DB among the 2 nodes

Comment: using embedded LDAP how to share UM_DB among the wso2is and wso2 API manager

Comment: see step 3 of https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager